# Is there a way to get didSet to work when changing a property in a class?

Tags: swift, observers, propertychanged, didset

I have a class as property with a property observer. If I change something in that class, is there a way to trigger didSet as shown in the example:

```
class Foo {
    var items = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var number: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            items += [number]
        }
    }
}

var test: Foo = Foo() {
    didSet {
        println("I want this to be printed after changing number in test")
    }
}

test.number = 1 // Nothing happens
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing happens because the observer is on `test`, which is a Foo instance. But you changed `test.number`, not `test` itself. Foo is a class, and a class is a reference type, so its instances are mutable in place.

If you want to see the log message, set `test` *itself* to a different value (e.g. a different `Foo()`).

Or, add the `println` statement to the *other* `didSet`, the one you've already got on Foo's `number` property.

Or, make Foo a struct instead of a class; changing a struct property *does* replace the struct, because a struct is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: of course... sometimes I want to hit myself having tried to find an answer over hours while I should have just used a struct... thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at my book, where I summarize the differences between the behaviors of value types vs. reference types: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes Response of `didSet` on a struct reference to a change in a property of the struct is one of the first examples I give.