# Why property observer doesn't work with classes?

Tags: swift, class, struct, property-observer

*Using Playground.*

I have the following structure:

```
struct Foo {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

I declared an instance from it as property observer with default values as "James" for the `name` and 33 for the `age`:

```
var myFoo = Foo(name: "James", age: 33) {
    willSet {
        print("my foo will be: \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        print("my foo was: \(oldValue)")
    }
}
```

When trying to edit the `name` of the instance:

```
myFoo.name = "John"
```

I could see on the log:

> my foo will be: Foo(name: "John", age: 33)
>
> my foo was: Foo(name: "James", age: 33)

which is my expectation. However, when declaring `Foo` as a class instead of structure: `class Foo` and running the exact same code, nothing will appear on the log.

What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a class is a reference type, whereas a struct is a value type.

- Suppose Foo is a class. `myFoo` is merely a reference. Saying `myFoo.name = "John"` mutates the object in place; no new value is assigned to `myFoo`, so the setter observer has nothing to observe.
- Suppose Foo is a struct. That's a value type. It cannot be mutated in place. Thus, saying `myFoo.name = "John"` actually replaces the struct in the variable `myFoo` with a new struct; that sets the variable and the setter observer fires.

---

That is also why you can say `myFoo.name = "John"` for a class even if `myFoo` was declared with `let` (i.e. the object is merely mutated in place), but you can't do that with a struct — you have to have declared `myFoo` with `var` so that the variable value can be replaced.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. So updating a property of `Foo` instance doesn't mean the instance itself has been reset. I think that was my misunderstanding...

Comment: Also, as you mentioned in the [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453735/is-there-a-way-to-get-didset-to-work-when-changing-a-property-in-a-class), if I typed `myFoo = Foo(name: "new", age: 101)` I can see expected result on the log.

Comment: Exactly: with a class, you won't see anything unless you actually _explicitly_ replace the instance with another instance. But a struct is different: it _implicitly_ replaces the instance with another instance merely because you set a property.